# Supress specific output lines of a command

Tags: linux, ls, output, stderr, filter

I wanted to search all the files starting with **`chrom`** in `/var` directory. So I executed this

```
$ ls -R | grep "^chrom"
```

To my astonishment, It showed [this](https://ghostbin.com/paste/8okm8). Few starting lines look like this :

```
amit@ElMaverick:/var$ ls -R | grep "^chromium"

chromium-browser_55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263_amd64.deb
chromium-browser-l10n_55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263_all.deb
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263_amd64.deb
ls: cannot open directory './cache/apt/archives/partial': Permission denied
ls: cannot open directory './cache/cups': Permission denied
ls: cannot open directory './cache/ldconfig': Permission denied
chromium-browser_chromium-browser.png
chromium-browser_chromium-browser.png
chromium-bsu_chromium-bsu.png
chromium-browser_chromium-browser.png
ls: cannot open directory './lib/apt/lists/partial': Permission denied
ls: cannot open directory './lib/bluetooth/78:0C:B8:46:10:D5': Permission denied
chromium-browser.conffiles
chromium-browser-l10n.list
chromium-browser-l10n.md5sums
chromium-browser.list
chromium-browser.md5sums
chromium-browser.postinst
chromium-browser.prerm
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra.list
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra.md5sums
ls: cannot open directory './lib/mysql': Permission denied
ls: cannot open directory './lib/mysql-files': Permission denied
```

I don't want to see these lines in the output.

```
ls: cannot open directory
```

So, I have 2 questions here :

1. How to filter only those lines which have no error of any type ?
2. Is there a way to supress the specific lines of output ?

Please provide a general approach for the problem, not just specific to this question.

Comment: A general approach is reliable only as far as programs reliably output "undesired" output to stderr; otherwise, you have to know what you don't want to see.

Answer (score 4):

1. Redirect the standard error stream of `ls` to `/dev/null`:

   ```
   ls -R 2>/dev/null | grep '^chrom'
   ```
2. Do further grepping:

   ```
   ls -R 2>/dev/null | grep '^chrom' | grep -v 'some additional pattern'
   ```

You may also consider using `find` ([Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)):

```
find . -name 'chrom*' ! -name 'some additional pattern' 2>/dev/null
```

Note that `find` uses filename globbing patterns while `grep` uses regular expressions.  With `find` you may also look specifically for files (with `-type f`) or for directories (`-type d`) etc., e.g.

```
find . -type f -name 'chrom*' ! -name 'some additional pattern' 2>/dev/null
```

Each part of the `find` command acts like a "test" against the found pathname. `-type` tests against the file type while `-name` tests against the final filename component of the path.  The tests are logically AND-ed together (unless `-o` is used).  An exclamation point inverts the sense of a test.

Answer (score 2):

Better use [find](/questions/tagged/find) it's better suites for this kind of tasks :

As simple user (because you don't have permission to read files as non root):

```
$ find /var -type f -name 'chrom*' 2>/dev/null
```

Or as root :

```
# find /var -type f -name 'chrom*'
```

And if you want to filter out a specific error in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), use :

```
command 2> >(grep -v 'specific error')
```

### Warning

[Never parse `ls` output !](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Still shows the same output including those error lines also.

Comment: Check my edited POST